# PBI IF statement for value that containts text and number

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to calculate the margin of products sold. This is not a problem, however I need the margin to equal 0 for three specific customers, as it are intra-company sales.

The customers are listed in our database as D99999.

I tried the following IF statement, however PowerBI does not find the customer field.
Margin = calculate(sum([margin](IF [customer]=D99999,0))).

Anyone able to help me? Also, how do I adjust the statement, in order for it to contain three customers?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Version-1

```
Margin_M =
CALCULATE ( IF ( [customer] = "D99999", 0, SUM ( [Margin] ) ) )
```

Version-2

```
Margin_M =
SUMX ( YourTable, IF ( YourTable[Customer] = "D99999", 0, YourTable[Margin] ) )
```

Version-3

If you want to add another customer(For example 'D6545') whose margin is zero(0), then try this:

```
Margin_M =
SUMX ( YourTable, IF(YourTable[Customer] IN {"D99999","D6545"}, 0, YourTable[Margin] ) )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. DAX doesn't recognize the [customer] field. That's the main issue that I'm having. Perhaps you are able to help me why?

Comment: Please put the table name in front : YourTableName[customer]

Comment: The funny thing is, the fields are both in the same table. I use only one table for this model. So the calculation would be (calculate(if('table1'[Customer] ........ but the [Customer] is not recognized by BI.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesnt recognize the value. It probably has something to do with the value being both string and numeric, but i don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: In the home tab, click "edit queries". It will lead you to Power Query editor. Select the customer column, right click it and pick "Change type" then select text. Then return to your code. test again.

Comment: Hello Please Try Version-2 in my solution. I updated it. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! Just one more question to you kind stranger, how would I modify the formula if I would want to add another customer whose margin needs to equal 0?

Comment: You are welcome! Then Try version-3 (I updated it)if you want to add another customer whose margin is 0. and please do not forget to accept my solution as the answer if it solves your problem.